# Implementing a DoublyLinkedList class with calling object

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I'm asked to implement a `ScoreBoard` class which has many methods:

> 1. `void add(GameEntry g)`: adds a new `GameEntry` object to `ScoreBoard`. The `GameEntry` object should be inserted into the scoreboard list such that the nodes of the list appear in non-increasing order of scores.
> 2. `void removeAll()`: clears the scoreboard by removing all game entries.
> 3. `void listScores()`: displays a list of available game scores in the scoreboard, in non-increasing order.

What I have came with is to create a `ScoreBoard` class which has `add(gameEntry)`, and extends my `DoublyLinkedList` class which utilize the `DNode <E>` as well as `removeAll()` and `listScores()` methods.

My Question: In the homework what I got is to implement `ScoreBoard` and `DoublyLinkedList` in the same class, I really tried to make them in one class, is  that possible?
In other words, Can I call an object from other class and implement it in my ADT doubly linked list class?

> ScoreBoard class:

```
public void add(GameEntry g) {

    if (g == null) {
        return;  }
    if (getHead() == null) {
        setHead(new DNode(g, null, null));
    } else if (g.getScore() > getHead().getElement().getScore()) {
        DNode<E> newHead = new DNode(g, null, getHead());
        getHead().setPrevious(newHead);
        setHead(newHead);
    } else if (getTail() != null && g.getScore() > getTail().getElement().getScore()) {
        DNode newTail = new DNode(g, getTail(), null);
        getTail().setNext(newTail);
        setTail(newTail);
    } else {
        DNode<E> pointer = getHead();
        while (pointer != null) {
            if (g.getScore() > pointer.getElement().getScore() && 
                    g.getScore() < pointer.getNext().getElement().getScore()) {
                pointer.setNext(new DNode(g, pointer, pointer.getNext()));
                pointer.getNext().getNext().setPrevious(pointer.getNext());
                pointer = pointer.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
    setSize(size()+1);
}


}
```

Update: Added code.

> GameEntry Class:

```
public class GameEntry {

private String name;
private int score;

public GameEntry(String n, int s) {
    name = n;
    score = s;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Name: %s | Score: %d", name, score);
}

 }
```

Comment: Is this a Connamacher assignment?

Comment: @EliSadoff It's not.

Comment: do you need actually to implement `DoublyLinkedList` class implementation or just methods add, removeAll, listScores in `ScoreBoard`? 
I would assume ScoreBoard would have doubleLinkedList as one of the properties and would be assigned from other class.

Comment: @alex I actually want to implement the methods add, remove, listScores.

Comment: First thing you need to ask yourself before you do any sort of extending through inheritance.. **is a DoublyLinkedList a Scoreboard?**

Answer (score 0):

You can create ScoreBoard with nested class inside, here is an example. But it all depends on your design of the overall game.

```
public class ScoreBoard {

    private DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();

    public ScoreBoard() {

    }

    public class DoublyLinkedList {

        private Node head;
        private Node tail;

        public DoublyLinkedList() {
            head = tail = null;
        }
    }

    private class Node {

        private String val;
        private Node next;
        private Node previous;

        public Node(String val, Node next, Node previous) {
            this.val = val;
            this.next = next;
            this.previous = previous;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps. As you can see you can have private and public nested classes. Check out java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Thank you, I have did what you've provided. I still can not call an object of GameEntry "cannot find symbol, method getScore() location: class object".

Comment: is it because GameEntry object doesn't have this method maybe? Can you provide some more code you have, including GameEntry class and where it is been initialised etc

Comment: have you debugged this, which line in `add(GameEntry g) {` is failing? Can you show how you initialise the GameEntry object? I noticed you have `getHead().getElement().getScore()` and `getTail().getElement().getScore() `what is this getElement() property? Seems like getScore it is not part of Element.

Comment: @DoeJ by the way, accept response it is answers your initial question